# Is there a way to format a column in a python pandas dataframe so that negative numbers are colored red and surrounded by parentheses?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to format a column in a python pandas dataframe so that negative numbers are colored red and surrounded by parentheses?

I have found a way to do one or the other but not both. Any ideas?

Comment: You could save time to a potential answerer by including the code that you have already used as well as some sample data. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . In regards to sample data and creating a minimum reproducible example, please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Please add your dataframe, codes you have tried and what errors you have met

Comment: [Styling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html) would be helpful for both conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have it as a number format and do what you want to do. you have to transform the numbers into strings. You can do it as follows

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Numbers':[1,2,2,-1,3,-4]})

   Numbers
0        1
1        2
2        2
3       -1
4        3
5       -4

#function to color the values that starts with parenthesis

def color_parenthesis_red(val):   
    color = 'red' if val.startswith('(') else 'black'
    return 'color: %s' % color

#transform values into string and add parenthesis when they are negative
df['Numbers']=df['Numbers'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: f"({x})" if int(x)<0 else x)

df.style.applymap(color_negative_red)
```

[image]